# Unable to install PostgreSQL server development packages on Centos7 server

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis

I am trying to configure `postgis-3.2.6dev` for PostgreSQL 15 using  `./configure`
But, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: the PGXS Makefile /usr/pgsql-15/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk cannot be found. Please install the PostgreSQL server development packages and re-run configure.
```

So, when I try to install the packages by using: `sudo yum install -y postgresql-server-dev-15`

It does not work

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 184.94.196.94
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 184.94.196.94
 * cpanel-plugins: 184.94.196.94
 * centos-sclo-rh: centos-distro.1gservers.com
No package postgresql-server-dev-15 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: The package is probably called `postgresql15-devel`.